# Incredibly high query times

Tags: neo4j

I am having some extremely high query times and I'm unable to pinpoint the issue.

I am having a graph database with 6685 nodes, 26407 properties and 22921 relationships, running on an Amazon EC2 instance having 1.7GB RAM.

My use case is to map people to their various interest points and find for a given user, who are the people who have common interests with him.

I have data about 500 people in my db, and each person has an average of a little more than 100 different interest points related to him.

1) When I run this cypher query:

```
START u=node(5) MATCH (u)-[:interests]->(i)<-[:interests]-(o) RETURN o;
```

Here node(5) is a user node. So, I am trying to find all users who have the same ":interests" relation with user (u).

This query return 2557 rows and takes about 350ms.

2) When I sprinkle in a few extra MATCH conditions, the query time exponentially degrades.

For eg., if I want to find all users who have common interests with user (u) = node(5), and also share the same hometown, I wrote:

```
START u=node(5) 
MATCH (u)-[:interests]->(i)<-[:interests]-(o) 

WITH u,o,i
MATCH (u)-[:hometown]->(h)<-[:hometown]-(o)
RETURN u, o, i, h;
```

This query return 755 rows and takes about 2500ms!

3) If I add more constraints to the MATCH, like same gender, same alma mater etc., query times progressively worsen to >10,000 ms.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try stating the pattern as a whole in your first `MATCH` clause, i.e. `MATCH (u)-[:interests]->(i)<-[:interests]-(o)-[:hometown]->(h)<-[:hometown]-(o)` ?

Comment: Maybe `WHERE (u)-[:hometown]->(h)<-[:hometown]-(o)` instead of the WITH...MATCH... would also help

Comment: I think the problem is that by using WITH and MATCH cypher first executes each MATCH clause separately, then builds the cartesian product and only afterwards does the joining by U,I,O. But this is more of a guess than anything.

Comment: Since the two patterns can be combined and expressed as one there shouldn't be a need for `WITH` or `WHERE` at all, or that was my idea. The OP does mention further constraints, possibly an extended set of constraints will not be expressible together in a single pattern. I don't know what would be best then, my sense would be to put constraints in a `WHERE` clause if they are simply extensions of the pattern, and divide the query with `WITH` only if write operations, aggregations or other operations are involved. I don't know the Cypher internals, so my $0.02 are humble. What do you think?